Titlesec paragraph
I would like to define the paragraph section such that it starts with the paragraph symbol. What is missing in the following?
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont}
{\P}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}
{0pt}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{.5em}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}
Test.
\end{document}


Let's review the syntax for \titleformat:
\titleformat{<level>}[<type>]
  {<general settings>}
  {<instructions for numbered titles>}
  {<separation between number and title>}
  {<actions on the title>}
  [<final additions>]

Since \paragraph isn't numbered (by default), what you specify in the third mandatory argument is ignored.
If your aim is to just add ¶ at the beginning of the line:
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\P}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}
  {0pt}
  {1.5ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.2ex}
  {0.5em}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\paragraph{}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}

I commented out fontspec because it's not necessary for the code to work. Instead I added lipsum to get some context.

But you don't need titlesec for this.
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mypara}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{1.5ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.2ex}
  \noindent\P\hspace{0.5em}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\mypara
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}

The only difference is that you're not allowed to leave blank lines in input between \mypara and the following text.
